# Best efficient data structure to store URIs for a web Crawler in Java

Tags: java, database, data-structures, web-crawler

I am buiding a web Crawler I have implemented the parsing part. Now I want to store the URI obtained into a efficient data structure . What should i use?? I am using the Jena library for parsing.

Comment: An "efficient" data structure? Efficient how? You have a list of URIs. How many? How to you need to access them? What's wrong with a list?

Answer (score 1):

Crawlers generally use a `Queue` to keep the to be inspected URIs with an accompanying `Set` to check for duplicate before inserting the URIs in the aforementioned queue and putting the URI in the set after inspecting it.

If the number of your links can fit in-memory, you can just be a `LinkedList` as the queue and a `HashSet` as the set. Otherwise you can use an external database for both purposes or a queuing server (like ActiveMQ) as the queue and a database as the set.

Comment: thanks. I also want to associate a value to each element of the Set is it possible??

Answer (score 1):

Generally in web crawling applications - you need to manage urls to discard [spider traps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_trap) (sometimes called "black holes"), discard frequent visits to the same page, also you'll use url as a global identifier of page content.

But the other interesting moment - is that *it is wrong to discard visiting the same urls twice* (**because content of web page may change in time**).

So the best way to satisfy these requirements is to use some kind of **priority queue** and associate each url with tuple: {url, **hash(url)**}. When you get new url - just calculate its hash, and if you have in your database records with same hash - just set low priority to this url and put it into the priority queue.

Web crawler asks priority queue for url to visit. So only pages, which has urls with highest priority would be visited primarily.

You may construct own hash function which fits your needs in the best way (for example - remove parameters from url string and calculate hash from the rest of string).

Comment: it means I have to make a priority queue of Hash Map(to store tuple{url,hash(url)}.

Comment: @Prannoy Mittal, No. I've described just a concept. I meant that you have to store in your storage both: hash and url (for example, if it is relational db - just make two columns for url and for hash, also you may add index for column with hash, because you'll compare urls by hashes). So if you get some url: - firstly calculate its hash, secondly - check if such hash exists in your storage. If exists - set low priority (if not exists - set high priority) - and add this url to queue.

Answer (score 0):

Hash.

E.g: URL: scheme://domain:port/path?query_string#fragment_id.

After the parsing the URL as strings, store the url as:

hash['scheme'] = scheme;

hash['domain'] = domain;

hash['port'] = port;

hash['path'] = path;

hash['query_string'] = query_string;

hash['fragment_id'] = fragment_id;

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to automatically discard duplicates so no URI is crawled twice? Then I would suggest a [HashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

It automatically discards duplicates and the insertion complexity is still constant in the optimal case. Note that when you use your own class to represent URIs and not the default class [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html), you will have to override the [`int hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) method of your URI class to return a text-based hash of the URI string. The default method of Object creates an unique hash code for each object, even when the content is identical.

Comment: Why not use the standard `java.net.URI` that already defines its own `equals` and `hashCode` implementation?

Comment: I also want to associate a value to each element of the Set or HashSet is it possible??

Comment: In that case you need a HashMap. That's a data structure which stores key/value pairs. Key could be the URLs and the values any object which stores your information about the URLs. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: hey..Philipp I have read the Java Docs of Hash Map, I think it does provide option to increment value to particular key dynamically. I require this function of dyanmically increment value for a key.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the queue of URI's to process and the already processed URI's in Redis (http://redis.io/). Redis is a very fast semi-persistent key-value store with native support for various data structures including lists (the queue of URIs) and hashes (maps). That way these data structures will survive a restart of your Java application. You can also probably have multiple instances of your app running without too much trouble communicating via Redis.

Comment: You'll quickly run out of memory if you store all these urls in redis. no?

Comment: you will run out of memory. To store 1B URLs you will need approx. 50GB of RAM. yes, redis will do BGSAVE but it will make redis unuseful in this case.